# Post request from Console to API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net

I'm trying to create random values and send them to controller which is in mvc api controller.But my datas in api always come 0 or null like their default. In console app i'm creating them but my datas come null or 0. What is my real problem?

My console code:

```
using MSE.DTO.DTOs.WorkStation;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http.Json;
using System.Text;

var random = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
var data = new WorkStationRandomValueDTO
{
    WorkStationId = random.Next(1, 100),
    Temperature = (decimal)Math.Round(random.NextDouble() * 100, 2),
    Pressure = (decimal)Math.Round(random.NextDouble() * 2000, 2),
    Status = random.Next(0, 1) == 1
};


using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:5002/WorkStationRandom/Post", content);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"WorkStationId: {data.WorkStationId}\nTemperature: {data.Temperature}\nPressure: {data.Pressure}\nStatus: {data.Status}\n ");
        Console.WriteLine("Data posted successfully");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error occured while posting data");
        Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

My Mvc Api Code :

```
using AutoMapper;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using MSE.DataAccess.Context;
using MSE.DTO.DTOs.WorkStation;
using MSE.Entity.Entities.Concrete;
using FromBodyAttribute = System.Web.Http.FromBodyAttribute;
using HttpGetAttribute = System.Web.Http.HttpGetAttribute;
using HttpPostAttribute = System.Web.Http.HttpPostAttribute;

namespace MSE.Web.Controllers
{
    public class WorkStationRandomController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        public WorkStationRandomController(ApplicationDbContext dbContext, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post([FromBody] WorkStationRandomValueDTO data)
        {
            if (data != null && data.WorkStationId != 0 && data.Temperature != 0 && data.Pressure != 0)
            {
                data.Status = true;
                var workStation = _mapper.Map<WorkStation>(data);
                _dbContext.WorkStations.Add(workStation);
                _dbContext.SaveChanges();

                return Ok();
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest("Data is not valid.");
            }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public string Get()
        {
            return "ok";
        }
    }
}
```

In this picture you can see my problem.

[image: image with zero values]

Thank you.

My point is that which create random values in console and send them to controller. But i always got 0 or null values.

Comment: Do you have `services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();` in your startup?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] that reproduces the problem.  Specifically, what is the definition of `WorkStationRandomValueDTO`?  E.g. does it have fields, or properties?

Comment: Yes, i have stuard but still it's not working. My only problem is my data comes null or 0.

Comment: @yigit_tanyel In your code I can see [FromBody], but image doesn't have it. It  should be. Also you need to post WorkStationRandomValueDTO class too

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to create random values and send them to controller which
> is in mvc api controller.But my datas in api always come 0 or null
> like their default. In console app i'm creating them but my datas come
> null or 0. What is my real problem?

Well, couple of things might cause you getting null data on your controller, first of all as [@Serge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11392290/serge) point out that in your code you have used [FromBody] but your screenshot missing it. My take on this, request should reach to your controller if you build it with valid  [class property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) and with no additional configuration on your [AddJsonOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.mvcjsonmvcbuilderextensions.addjsonoptions?view=aspnetcore-2.2&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-7.0) at your program.cs file according to your shared code snippet.

**Correct Request Format Based On Your Shared Code:**

Console App Snippet:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Text;

var random = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
var data = new WorkStationRandomValueDTO
{
    WorkStationId = random.Next(1, 100),
    Temperature = (decimal)Math.Round(random.NextDouble() * 100, 2),
    Pressure = (decimal)Math.Round(random.NextDouble() * 2000, 2),
    Status = random.Next(0, 1) == 1
};


using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
   
 
    var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:5094/WorkStationRandom/post", content);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"WorkStationId: {data.WorkStationId}\nTemperature: {data.Temperature}\nPressure: {data.Pressure}\nStatus: {data.Status}\n ");
        Console.WriteLine("Data posted successfully");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error occured while posting data");
        Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    }
}


public class WorkStationRandomValueDTO
{
    public int WorkStationId { get; set; }
    public decimal Temperature { get; set; }
    public decimal Pressure { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }

   
}
```

API Code Snippet:

```
public class WorkStationRandomController : ControllerBase
    {
       
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post([FromBody] WorkStationRandomValueDTO data)
        {
            if (data != null && data.WorkStationId != 0 && data.Temperature != 0 && data.Pressure != 0)
            {
                //data.Status = true;
                //var workStation = _mapper.Map<WorkStation>(data);
                //_dbContext.WorkStations.Add(workStation);
                //_dbContext.SaveChanges();

                return Ok();
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest("Data is not valid.");
            }
        }
    }

    public class WorkStationRandomValueDTO
    {
        public int WorkStationId { get; set; }
        public decimal Temperature { get; set; }
        public decimal Pressure { get; set; }
        public bool Status { get; set; }
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:**

Any additional, configurations which has not been shared will not be considered here.

**Why Then Yours One Not Working:**

**1.** If you have any configuration in program.cs which has not shared
with us:

If you follow my above sample, your request should reach to your controller with valid data as you can see in given debug capture. In this scenario you do  not need [builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddJsonOptions(options =>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-7.0#options-interfaces) on your program.cs file.

For instance: If you have any additional property on your AddJsonOptions  which you haven't shared that also might cuase the issue.

**2.** If you define WorkStationRandomValueDTO as Property as Field

Inside your WorkStationRandomValueDTO  class if you define WorkStationId, Temperature and others member as [Fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields) just as following:

```
public class WorkStationRandomValueDTO
    {
        public int WorkStationId;
        public decimal Temperature;
        public decimal Pressure;
        public bool Status;
    }
```

Fields instead of [Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) might cause null data in your controller as per your shared code. It doesn't mean that you cannot send field value but the way you are sending request at this moment that cause null parameter.

Therefore, above two issue can cause your empty reuqest at your controller. Here I have the reproduce your scenario accordingly.

**Issue Reproduced With Null Parameter:**

[image]